# How to subsetting dataframes based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have to data frames, returns.df and funds.df with identical dimensions:

```
returns1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9)
returns2 <- c(0.3,0.4,0.7,0.1)
returns.df <- data.frame(returns1,returns2)
returns.df

funds1 <- c("Fund A","Fund B","","Fund D")
funds2 <- c("Fund B","Fund C","","Fund A")
funds.df <- data.frame(funds1, funds2)
funds.df
```

I am trying to store 4 subsets of returns for each of the funds. For example, the subset Fund Returns for fund A would look like:

```
returns.FundA1 <- c(0.1,"","","")
returns.FundA2 <- c("","","",0.11)
returns.FundA.df <- data.frame(returns.FundA1, returns.FundA2)
returns.FundA.df
```

Basically I want to create a new data.frame where I just replace the Fund name in fund.df separately by its returns in returns.df, but in a new data.frame. 
Normally I would do this in excel across multiple sheets using a simple if function. But I am confident that this can be done much faster in R. 
I appreciate any inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's personal preference, but I would reshape my data to long format, where everything is contained in the same object. Then subsetting (or performing operations for each fund) is easy. If you're doing the same thing for each fund, creating a separate dataframe for each is unnecessary, and it'll be a lot of work.

```
#create ID based on row number/name
#returns.df$id <- rownames(returns.df)
#funds.df$id <- rownames(funds.df)

returns.df$id <- 1:nrow(returns.df)
funds.df$id <- 1:nrow(funds.df)

#combine them (based on these IDs)
return.funds <- merge(returns.df, funds.df, by="id")
```

Then, we turn this combined, 'wide' dataset to long format. As we have two distinct measures that vary (return and fund, both have a first and a second value), we use data.table as it's melt-function is able to deal with multiple `measure`-columns. We set the pattern and names in the melt-function.

```
#turn to long
library(data.table)
return.funds.m <- melt(setDT(return.funds),
    measure.vars=patterns(c("returns","funds")),
    value.name=c("return","fund"))
```

Now our data looks like this:

```
   id variable return   fund
1:  1        1    0.1 Fund A
2:  2        1    0.2 Fund B
3:  3        1    0.5       
4:  4        1    0.9 Fund D
5:  1        2    0.3 Fund B
6:  2        2    0.4 Fund C
7:  3        2    0.7       
8:  4        2    0.1 Fund A
#example: select fund A
```

Say we wanted to get the mean return for both time-points for each fund, we could do this:

```
return.funds.m[,mean(returns), by=fund]
```

For how to run/examine  multiple models, I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721842/loop-linear-regression-and-saving-coefficients/34722046#34722046) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323389/loop-linear-regression-and-saving-all-coefficients?lq=1) answer.

Comment: I actually thought of something like this. However, my dataset is enormous and fund names can change, which is why I find the best way to replace the fund name by its respective return in the same element. Also I am doing this, because I want to examine each fund by OLS regression seperately.

Comment: For the first part, I'm not sure what you mean. Can one fund have different names? For the second part, this can be done in data.table.

Comment: I mean, I have multiple columns, where for example Fund A in columnC in row 2 can change it name to Fund B in columnD row 2. Wouldn't this cause a problem? I should perhaps tell the goal here. So I want to compute the arithmetic mean across each fund, over time. My idea was then create a subset of each funds, and then use the apply function.

Comment: I might not understand the problem correctly, but I don't think it will. I will add some more explanation in my answer. Still unsure what you mean by 'changed' names; the melt-function in data.table can handle multiple measures across multiple columns, as long as the naming is consistent.

Comment: I think I might overthink it. I am trying to run your code

Comment: > > return.funds.m[fund=="Fund A",]
Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
> id variable return   fund
Error: unexpected symbol in "id variable"
> 1:  1        1    0.1 Fund A
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "1:  1        1"
> 2:  4        2    0.1 Fund A
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "2:  4        2"

Comment: Do your original data have rownames that are characters? If so, does it solve your problem if you create the id's by `1:nrow(...)`?

Comment: The unexpected '>' happends if you try to run code like it's in console (with a '>' at the start, remove it from the line in the script

Comment: I see. I will check the rowsnames

Comment: I do have problems with rownames

Comment: I added new codes, which uses row indices. Does that solve it?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't want to beat my own drum, but if the question is solved to your satisfaction, could you consider accepting the answer? Keeps others from spending time on the question.